# Sonarqube and java assert

Tags: java, sonarqube

I just started to use sonarqube on one of my repos and now I wonder how to get rid of this

[image]

When running without assertions I do not want do anything! I.e. sonarqube wants me to do

```
boolean isKing = piece.getType() == KING;
assert !isKing
```

But that would cost "computrons" when I am not running in assert mode.

And why is the assert above not marked!?

Comment: is `piece.getType()` simple getter (with no side effect) or does it change internal state of `ChessPiece` (I guess no) ?

Comment: It is a simple getter!

Comment: The simplest and probably most correct way to get rid of this warning is to disable it in the sonar configuration. Just remember that not every warning produced by the static analysis is right or useful.

Comment: Yea I guess so. The sad thing is that sometimes these warnings actually indicates a bug.

Comment: With https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2159 this rule should have become much less 'noisy' which was released in SonarJava 4.7. Could you verify that you have at least that version?

Comment: I am using gradle. I.e.  apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'. Where can I see the version of the SonarJava!? In my sonarqube install !?

Comment: Hum .. I found something in sonarqube server admin update center where I had a really old version. I updated from SonarJava 3.13 to SonarJava 4.9. Strange since my Sonarqube was installed just some days ago!

Comment: I was on the latest LTS version but have now switched to 6.5.

Comment: The bundled SonarJava of the 5.6 LTS is 3.13 (That was the SonarJava plugin version at the time). At this point in time the latest SonarJava version is 4.14 which you should be able to install through the Update Center page. This gives you the benefit of all the new rules, analysis flow improvements and fixes on False Postives and False Negatives.